# How to represnt "data-othersrc" in thymeLeaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I am using thymeLeaf at view side. I need to write given statement in thymeLeaf

```
<div>
<img data-othersrc="images/mobile_banner.jpg" src="images/banner.png" alt="img" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

I am able to write **src** as  **th:src="@{${demo.value}}** in  thymeLeaf then how can I do it for **data-othersrc**?

Answer (score 0):

The standard standard syntax for html5 attributes in Thymeleaf would be `th:` followed by attribute per [5.6 Support for HTML5-friendly attribute and element names](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#support-for-html5-friendly-attribute-and-element-names). Examples of html elements utilizing `data-` can be found there. Try using the following in your tag, similar to how you utilized `th:src`. This is without the `@` which would be reserved for [Link URL Expressions](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls).

```
<img th:data-othersrc="${demo.value}" th:src="@{${demo.value}}" th:alt="img" th:class="img-responsive">
```

> The data-{prefix}-{name} syntax is the standard way to write custom attributes in HTML5, without requiring developers to use any namespaced names like th:*. Thymeleaf makes this syntax automatically available to all your dialects (not only the Standard ones).

Now if `${demo.value}` within the `th:src` is not resolving, then this could be an issue the `demo` object being sent to the template from your controller.

Comment: I  hav tried it .In this case it coming  as it is  not paring it.In page source code I am getting this <img th:data-othersrc="@{${demo.value}}" alt="img" class="img-responsive" src="https://assets.stayuncle.com/19/19-1.jpg" />
                    </div>

Comment: Actually try the full tag in the edit. I realized only `th:src` and `th:href` may likely be able to use the `@` prefix. `${demo.value}` should hopefully resolve for that custom attribute as `@` prefix is for Link URL Expressions specifically.

Comment: tried with suggested change but didn't work out .Its not able to parse this annotation.

Comment: Could you please try any other HTML5 element instead of `th:data-othersrc="${demo.value}"` such as `th:data-toggle="${demo.value}"` or `<td data-th-text="${demo.value}">...</td>` (within table) to see if ANY HTML5 will resolve? If no custom elements resolve, this could be an issue of Thymeleaf versions. HTML5 custom elements functionality such as the one you are attempting to use was only introduced in one of the most latest versions which is 2.1.x   Could you please upgrade to 2.1 and attempt to insert one of these custom elements?

Comment: I tried , result remain same .  I want to implement this option because I want use different image source  in mobile for our application as                     <img data-othersrc="images/mobile_banner3.jpg" src="images/desktopbanner3.png" alt="img" class="img-responsive">
.  As this data-othersrc option is not working. is there any other way to provide other source path for images and that is supported in thymeleaf also?

Comment: My concern so far is that NO th:data-{foo}-{bar} seems to be rendering/resolving for your project. Assuming you are using at least 2.1.x version of Thymeleaf, this may be an entirely separate issue. Have you tried any other th:data-{foo}-{bar} with some test values to see if any custom attribute works? If you are looking for resizing images dynamically based on viewport size you could perhaps consider something like [picturefll](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85431/discussion-between-nand-and-alexander-staroselsky).

Comment: In my project I am using <thymeleaf.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
in my project I have used th:src, th:href,th:text,th:field,th:placeholder
all are working , I have also tried out th:data-toggle="${demo.value}" and<td data-th-text="${demo.value}">...</td> that you suggested in last post but that didn't work out . Can you please guide me what are option left for me ?

Comment: This may not be ideal option performance wise, but if you absolutely need it, you could utilize javascript and/or jQuery to collect the `src` attribute values that are resolving correctly, then populate this custom element data-othersource with that value

Comment: @ Alexander  what are best practices to make thing work on mobile . My app contain big images. I want to make my website responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this:

```
<img th:attr="data-othersrc=@{${demo.value}}"
     th:src="@{${demo.value}}">
```

It works for me.